# how to append a dynamic number to a variable name of string data type in java?

Tags: java

```
   for(int i=0;i<counter;i++){
            String textbox+""i=request.getParameter("text1"+i); 
        }
```

i am trying to use variable name dynamically but it 
says that the left hand side assignment must be a variable.I don't know how  to append this numbers to the variable name using double quotes ,i am a fresher to programming .

Comment: this `textbox+""i` is not an identifer

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use an array o Strings:

```
String[] textbox = new String[counter];
for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
{
  textbox[i]=request.getParameter("text1"+i); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same with a Map like that, you'll be able to retrieve your parameters with their names, which can make more sense than just a `List`:

```
Map<String, Object> textbox = new HashMap<>();
for(int i=0;i<counter;i++) {
    String paramId = "text"+i;
    textbox.put(paramId, request.getParameter(paramId));
}
```

But please note this is kind of useless since the parameters in the request are already a Map. You can directly pass the map (`using request.getParameterMap()`) to your methods and use it later.